# Strange PageDown behaviour in presence of folds

Tags: vim, folding

I observe the following strange behaviour in Vim 7.3:

When I'm below a fold, pressing PageDown jumps *up* to that fold, the next few PageDown presses don't move me out of that fold, and only then PageDown actually jumps down the buffer. The fold remains closed during these operations.

When there are no folds, PageDown works as expected.

Is there any way to make PageDown simply ignore the folds?

UPDATE. This happens only when folds are big enough (because presumably PageDown is moving "inside" that fold).

Comment: Uhmm, it should jump over folded lines like they're not there, were things as usual. Could it be that you have it mapped to something(?) somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be mapped to anything.

Comment: It returns "No mapping found."? Then sorry, I'm out of ideas ... :/

Comment: One more thing. Is there any difference in Ctrl-F and PageDown behaviour (they should do the same thing)?

Comment: They do the same thing indeed,

Comment: @ldigas -- I've updated the question -- can you reproduce it now?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the incorrect behavior.  Could you please create a small test case (a file with specified boundaries of the folded text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this behaviour is caused by the [window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27window%27) option being set (to an integer value). If I unset it, everything works great.